# Fix corrupt environment conda

Tags: conda

In conda, when I tried to install a package, I got this error:

```
 CorruptedEnvironmentError: The target environment has been corrupted. Corrupted environments most commonly
    occur when the conda process is force-terminated while in an unlink-link
    transaction.
      environment location: /home/user/anaconda3/envs/myenv
      corrupted file: /home/user/anaconda3/envs/myenv/conda-meta/qt-5.9.7-h5867ecd_1.json
```

I think my RAM is kind of messed up due to previous electricity disconnections so that might be the cause of this. How would I fix this?

Answer (score 21):

The following worked for me. TL;DR of @Jordan's answer.

1. Try to install package again via conda
2. Remove the file claimed to be corrupt
3. Repeat steps 1 and 2 until package successfully installs
4. Run `conda update --all` for good measure

Answer (score 8):

I faced the same problem and the only solution was to manually delete the file which is mentioned to be corrupted in the error prompt and try to install the package again. Upon running `conda install` command again i got the same error prompt but this time the corrupted file was different. Repeating the same process until the error goes away solves the problem and eventually you will be able to install the required package.

After successful installation just update all packages once using the following command:

```
conda update --all
```

Answer (score 3):

1. `conda update --force-reinstall <package_name>`.
2. If the above step displays an error, remove the conda package folder mentioned int he error message, as the downloaded package may be corrupt: `rm -rf <directory>`. (The directory name should match this pattern: `~/anaconda3/pkgs/<package_name>*`).

   Then `conda update --force-reinstall <package_name>` again and you are done.

Note that the downloaded package can easily be corrupted as the installed version uses the same files. That is, if you edit an installed file, the one in the download folder will also change. This is why you need to delete the downloaded package before being able to restore a file.